# ResultSet returns only one row

Tags: sql, oracle, hashmap, resultset

I've this code with 3 results, but system show only one...

```
Map<String, String> mappaValori = tvo.getTableColumn();
while (resultSet.next()) {
    for (String colonnaString : mappaValori.keySet()) {
        valueString = resultSet.getString(colonnaString);
        keyString = colonnaString;
        mappaReturn.put(keyString, valueString);
    }
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: ...but...why -1??? -.-

Comment: I didn't downgrade your question, but I suspect the reason that somebody did is that you didn't provide enough information.  Ideally you would provide more context (so for example you claim there should be three elements in the result set, but there is nothing to support that claim).  Ideally you would also provide enough information to enable someone to recreate the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very thanks to all (I'm ironic)!

I don't know why some person click on -1 but I've the solution!

I share this:

When resultset.next(), the map overwrites result and show only one row .